# Getting java.lang.AbstractMethodError when I test using REST Assured

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, junit, rest-assured

I'm trying to test a REST api defined in my controller class using `REST Assured v4.3.0`, but I get `java.lang.AbstractMethodError` when I run the test. I understand this error is occurring because I'm calling an abstract method, but I'm having a hard time resolving it.

It seems that the error is occurring due to `.body(is(equalTo("success")))` in `SampleControllerTest.java` because when I remove this line, the test succeeds. I tried a few things to resolve it, but didn't get any success:

- Searched online for suggestions and examples, but they are either for older versions or not related to `io.rest-assured/spring-mock-mvc`
- Tried different matchers (`org.hamcrest.Matchers.*` and `org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*`)
- Tried adding `org.hamcrest/hamcrest` dependency in the pom file explicitly

Here's my code for your reference:

**Code structure:**

```
test
|- src/
|  |- main/
|  |  |- java/
|  |  |  |- org/
|  |  |  |  |- example/
|  |  |  |  |  |- Application.java
|  |  |  |  |  |- SampleController.java
|  |- test/
|  |  |- java/
|  |  |  |- org/
|  |  |  |  |- example/
|  |  |  |  |  |- SampleControllerTest.java
|- target/
|- pom.xml
```

**Application.java**

```java
package org.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**SampleController.java**

```java
package org.example;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class SampleController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/sample")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public String getSample() {
        return "success";
    }
}
```

**SampleControllerTest.java**

```java
package org.example;

import org.junit.Test;

import static io.restassured.module.mockmvc.RestAssuredMockMvc.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

public class SampleControllerTest {
    @Test
    public void testGetSample() {
        given()
            .standaloneSetup(new SampleController())
            .when()
            .get("/sample")
            .then()
            .assertThat(status().isOk())
            .body(is(equalTo("success")));
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <start-class>org.example.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/spring-mock-mvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mock-mvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/json-path -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/xml-path -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-path</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I run the test using `mvn test`, this is the error I get:

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.325 s <<< FAILURE! - in org.example.SampleControllerTest
[ERROR] testGetSample(org.example.SampleControllerTest)  Time elapsed: 1.288 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method io/restassured/internal/ResponseSpecificationImpl.getProperty(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object; is abstract
        at org.example.SampleControllerTest.testGetSample(SampleControllerTest.java:20)
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `io.rest-assured/spring-mock-mvc` dependency was conflicting with `io.rest-assured/rest-assured` dependency. Once I removed the `io.rest-assured/rest-assured` from `pom.xml`, the test worked successfully.

A few years ago when I was using REST Assured version `3.1.1`, I could keep both of these dependencies, but perhaps newer versions don't allow this.

Answer (score 16):

Because of rest-assured 4.3.0 upgrade the Groovy from 2.5.7 to 3.0.2, see [rest-assured/changelog.txt at master · rest-assured/rest-assured](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/blob/master/changelog.txt), you can specified the groovy version in pom file.

```xml
  <properties>
    <rest-assured.version>4.3.0</rest-assured.version>
    <groovy.version>3.0.2</groovy.version>
  </properties>
```

Comment: For Gradle, that would be `ext["groovy.version"] = "3.0.3"` (Groovy DSL) or `extra.apply {        set("groovy.version", "3.0.3") }` (Kotlin DSL).

Answer (score 9):

It looks like a bug in REST Assured 4.3.0, your code works with 4.2.0 version.

I didn't find opened issue. https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues

Comment: That might be true. When I removed the `io.rest-assured/rest-assured` dependency and kept `io.rest-assured/spring-mock-mvc`, it worked fine.

Comment: Ops... I do what you do and works too!  

I change from "io.rest-assured/rest-assured" to io.rest-assured/spring-mock-mvc  

And add  in pom.xml  


```xml  
 
<io-rest-assured.version>4.3.0</io-rest-assured.version>  

<dependency>  

<groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>  

<artifactId>spring-mock-mvc</artifactId>  

<version>${io-rest-assured.version}</version>  

<scope>test</scope>  

</dependency>  

```

Comment: No, it is not a bug in REST Assured, but in the dependency resolution. Something (Spring in this case) depends on Groovy 2.1.3 (for all artifacts). REST Assured depends on Groovy 3.0.2 (or 3.0.3), but declares only top-level dependencies, not `org.codehaus.groovy:groovy` itself – Spring wins.

Answer (score 6):

I used 4.2.0 instead of 4.3.0 .. it works for me

Comment: Im use resolution above comment by @jörg-pfründer  its works for with 4.3.1 version  
  
I put in build.gradle this:  
  
```groovy
configurations.all {  
    resolutionStrategy.cacheDynamicVersionsFor 10, "minutes"  

    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { 
        DependencyResolveDetails details ->  
            if (details.requested.group == 'org.codehaus.groovy') {  
                details.useVersion "3.0.2"  
                details.because "needed by rest-assured>=4.3"  
            }  
    }  
}  
```

Answer (score 5):

For Maven projects, the code below works well with Spring Boot projects:

````xml
<properties>
       <groovy.version>3.0.7</groovy.version>
       <rest-assured.version>4.3.3</rest-assured.version>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-mock-mvc</artifactId>
           <scope>test</scope>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
                   <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
           <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
           <version>${groovy.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
           <artifactId>groovy-xml</artifactId>
           <version>${groovy.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
           <artifactId>groovy-json</artifactId>
           <version>${groovy.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
           <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
           <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
           <artifactId>xml-path</artifactId>
           <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```
````

Answer (score 4):

I also had an `java.lang.AbstractMethodError` but on another method.

rest-assured 4.3 upgraded it's implementation to use [groovy 3](https://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-3.0.html), see [rest assured's release notes](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/blob/master/changelog.txt)

In my case the dependency resolution downgraded groovy to use some 2.x version.

If you use maven:

You can check that using `mvn dependency:tree`. 
If there's a conflict, add the necessary groovy dependencies as direct dependencies with a version=>3.0.2 to your project.

If you use gradle:

You can check that using `gradle depencencies`.
If there's a conflict, then add a resolution strategy:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'org.codehaus.groovy') {
            details.useVersion "3.0.2"
            details.because "needed by rest-assured>=4.3"
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe that can help somebody.

Comment: Or, perhaps shorter or more readable: `constraints { iplementation("org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.3") { because("Needed by REST Assured") }    }`

Answer (score 2):

Use below dependency  of rest assured in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use Rest Assured version `4.3.2`, just specify **explictly** the groovy version to `3.0.6` and that fixes the error.

```
<rest-assured.version>4.3.2</rest-assured.version>
<groovy.version>3.0.6</groovy.version>
```

Good luck.